# Why does adding constraints for all four sides cause an error?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

**UPDATE**

[image]Editing an XIB file, I added a button to the position that I'd like in the view and clicked the pin icon at the bottom right, and pinned all four sides of the button, with "Constrain to Margins" unchecked, as that's the exact location I would want to place the button and I wouldn't want it to move around.

But I got an error that says 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.' Why does that happen?

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out     which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x9f494b0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x9f40370(20)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x9f3b6c0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x9f40370]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9f3feb0 )>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x9f418e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x9f407c0(0)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x9f18010 _UILayoutGuide:0x9f407c0.bottom == UIView:0x9f3feb0.bottom>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9f40f10 V:[UIButton:0x9f40f40'Button']-(211)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x9f407c0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9f47ab0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x9f40370]-(539)-[UIButton:0x9f40f40'Button']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa157b10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x9f3feb0(568)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: IIRC the log message displays the constraints in question. Can you add this to your Q?

Comment: you should read or watch any tutorial about Auto Layout.
for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bprcg7ysyNA

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout technology work on relationship between objects and object with superview how they will draw on screen. as you mention you are trying to force object through all sides so set for specific position you can try by think how object will draw on screen by applying specific constraints.

if you want to place object of fix width and height at center of screen in all orientation then you can try

Align->Horizontal and Vertical center in container.
(Otherwise even they can crash your app if unsatisfied constraints)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have fixed width and height for the button but I want it to pin it to the exact position it is placed in. So I pinned all 4 sides, but I am getting an error. What may be the problem? Still don't seem to figure it out. Thank you

Comment: At which position do you want to put? you can pin to 4 side if your view cover full screen. in case of button for 4 side constraints autolayout system start adding constraints from top ,left so for Any any size class your button put 250 pixel so it pushed to right so. it better to add other constraints like Trailing,Leading,horizontally ,vertically center in container.

Comment: I updated with a screenshot. I would like it to be located at that exact location, and be able to stay at that location through different views as well, such as landscape etc. What would be the best way to achieve so?

Comment: 539+30+211>self.view.frame.size.height due to this it is not possible to put your button object on screen exact position you want in screen..same to width. hope you understand this time

Answer (score 0):

If you have a height or width assigned to the button it will conflict with the constraints you added. If you want it to always be at a certain x,y and specific size you should pin the top and left along with the width and height. If you want it to dynamically resize you should pin all 4 sides.

Comment: I pinned all 4 sides, but I received an error. What may be the reason?

Comment: You do not want to pin all 4 sides if you have a width and height pinned. Unpinning the right and bottom side is most likely what you are looking for.

Comment: I pinned only two sides, yet it isn't located in the exact location that I'd like it to be on the Storyboard. On the simulator, it is located elsewhere. What would be the best way to just place an object at an exact location, being able to adjust in different views as well? Thank you!

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. It might be that you want to pin it to the bottom right instead, or you can center it as well. I'd suggest going through this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1